# detect SSL SNI support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, sni

Is there any way to detect SNI SSL support in rails? Judging from [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), I could probably know there's no SNI support if user agent is IE on win XP. However, I'm looking for a more generic solution. Thanks.

Comment: Since Rails et al. is server side and SNI support is a browser/client dependent; my answer to ["Is SNI actually used and supported in browsers?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154596/is-sni-actually-used-and-supported-in-browsers) with JavaScript implementation details should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the short answer is: no. It's up to the client to support validating your cert using the SNI protocol. So all you can do is use a white or black list (there probably is a pretty good one out there somewhere).

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading: the client does not *validate* a cert using SNI, and there's no *white or black list* that would be useful here because by the time you have any information about the specific client (e.g. a user-agent string), the HTTPS handshake has already completed and the server was already forced to select a certificate.