# More than one certificate on Apache (namebased)?

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, ssl-certificate, vhosts

I need to install 3 different certificates on my apache - but I only got 1 IP(v4).

Is there a mod(for apache) or whatever to use more than one certificate on namebased vhost's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNI is supported in apache since 2.2

see http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Thank you - in the meentime I found this http://www.der-eremit.de/post/13589628448/ssl-enabled-name-based-virtual-hosts-with-mod-gnutls but I think it is outdated...

Comment: I guess there is no way to host it also for WinXP clients?!

Comment: If the xp client is using IE then it looks like no.  If they use chrome/firefox etc then it will  work.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154596/is-ssl-sni-actually-used-and-supported-in-browsers

Comment: Perfect - than you solved my problem :-D Thank you